# 401 unauthorized on hitting endpoint using MSAL React Application authentication

Tags: typescript, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I'm following this tutorial to authenticate a react application using MSAL and call my own api using the authentication token: https://github.com/oizhaolei/typescript-msal-sample

I added the following code to make an api call:

```
import { loginRequest, config } from "../authConfig";
import { msalInstance } from "../index";

export async function callMsGraph() {
    const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
    if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account! Verify a user has been signed in and setActiveAccount has been called.");
    }

    const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: account
    });

    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`;
    
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch(config.endpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())        
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

authConfig.ts

```
import { Configuration } from "@azure/msal-browser";

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<client-id>",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/"
    }
};

// scopes
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["api://<client-id>/user_impersonation"]
};

// endpoints 
export const config = {
    endpoint: "https://xxx-webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/jobs"
};
```

On running this, I see 401 unauthorized error. What am I missing?

Comment: Before calling the api endpoint, can you check the bearer token and decode the details to see claims and provide decoded values here by masking sensitive values

Answer (score 0):

After login ,decode the access token  https://jwt.ms  and see which endpoint is present in issuer (“iss” claim) i.e `v1 or v2` and then go to azure ad portal and change the `accesstokenacceptedversion` if it not according to that endpoint i.e; it `must be null or 1 for V1` and `2 for V2`.

[image]

If it is correct , please make the required scopes are exposed for that api in portal and granted admin consent with api permissions.

[image]

In my case i am calling graph api endpoint but received **`401 audience invalid error`**.

[image]

As my `Aud` clailm doesn't match the clientId where my clientId is AppId and Audience is AppIdUri as per decoded claim:

[image]

But both must match.

In my case it worked when ClientId is given with api prefix i.e AppIdUrI: **`api://<clientId>`** ,

and given proper permissions like User.Read.All openid permissions and granted admin consent .

[image]

Got the access token when called token endpoint:
**https://login.microsoftonline.com/fxxxxx0/oauth2/v2.0/token**

```
client_id:api://b97xxx74876
client_secret:WWxxx.a5P
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image: worked token endpoint]

then called my api i.e; graph api in this case with the received token for graph
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What should I add the redirect uri in my application? I set it as http://localhost:3000 on running locally it worked however After deploying this change, I see 'localhost redfused to connect' error

Comment: Try changing the port number ex: ,
  https://localhost:44316 Or You can even try to replace the localhost with your IP address.
Also make sure ,no firewall blocking the connection and whatever port you change , make sure same is given in appregistration reply url and in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: You have registered the app under Azure AD rather than Azure AD B2C.

You should navigate to Azure AD B2C to register it. If you don't have an B2C tenant, just create it.

Although you can see the app under Azure AD B2C, it doesn't mean you created it here.

An app registered in Azure AD will be shown under Azure AD B2C - App registrations (Preview) as well.

**Option 2**: You have selected the wrong supported account type option.

You should select Accounts in any organizational directory or any identity provider. (for authenticating users with user flows) when you created it. Otherwise it won't be shown in B2C User Flow.

Check this one out "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133312/aadb2c90068-the-provided-application-with-id-is-not-valid-against-this-service"

**Option 2**: SOLVED FOR ME, changed this from false to true
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,